# firefox no longer being ignored by fiddler

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, fiddler

After updating firefox to 3.6.4, fiddlerhook no longer allows you to disable firefox traffic. It will always show up in fiddler. Is this a known issue with the new way firefox is handling add ins?

Comment: I've got 3.6.4 and don't see this problem (Fiddler hook version 2.2.8.9)

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing this problem with Adobe Flash requests? FF3.6.4 has a new feature that runs add-ons out-of-process, and I think they have a bug where the proxy setting from the main process isn't properly propagated to the background add-on process. I don't know if that's been filed in Mozilla's DB.

Restarting Firefox should resolve the issue.